# Why an undef variable becomes {} without define?

Tags: perl

I'm working on review webmin's [source code](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/master/password_change.cgi#L21).

`($wuser) = grep { $_->{'name'} eq $in{'user'} } &acl::list_users();`

If we pass `$in{'user'}` like `?user=notexist`, variable `$wuser` will be `undef`, isn't it?

The abstract code descript what happened below.

```perl
# $wuser is undef now.
#die Dumper($wuser);
if($wuser){die 'not die here';}
        if ($wuser->{'pass'} eq 'x') {
                #never reach here.
                die 'not die in branch 1';
        }
        elsif ($wuser->{'pass'} eq '*LK*' ||
               $wuser->{'pass'} =~ /^\!/) {
                #never reach here too.
                die 'not die in branch 2';
        }
if($wuser){die 'so....why die here '.Dumper($wuser);}
# $wuser is {} now.
}
```

So...when and how an undef variable becomes {} without any define...

Comment: Review with an eye towards improving it? So many things can be done better with that script... the line you quoted can benefit from using `first` from the `List::Util` module for starters.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is a Perl feature called "autovivification". Basically, it means that if you treat an undefined Perl variable as a type of reference, then Perl will create a reference of that type and store it in your variable.

So your problem starts when you execute this statement:

```
if ($wuser->{'pass'} eq 'x')
```

Perl sees you treating `$wuser` as a hash reference, so it creates an empty hash and stores a reference to that hash in `$wuser`. It can then look up the "pass" key in that hash and find that it doesn't exist.

Usually, this is seen as a feature. You can run code like:

```
my $hash; # created as undef
$hash->{foo}{bar}{baz} = 1;
```

And Perl will create this data structure for you:

```
{
  'foo' => {
    'bar' => {
      'baz' => 1
    }
  }
};
```

without you needing to go to the trouble of creating all the intermediate levels of the hash.

Of course, your code is rather artificial. You know that `$wuser` is false when you start looking for keys. All references are true, so a false reference can never contain keys.

Comment: One can use [`no autovivification;`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) to turn off/configure this behaviour.

Comment: One could also (more laboriously) use `ref` and `exists` guards before diving into data structures: `if (ref($foo) eq 'HASH' && exists $foo->{bar}) {...}`. Unwieldy, to be sure, but sometimes a sharper sword than the pragma.

Comment: @DavidO No need for `ref`. If you're expecting a reference or nothing, a simple truth test will do.